# multiple inheritance diamond problem without default constructor

Tags: c++

I end up with a multiple inheritance diamond problem with the situation that there is no default constructor in the base class.

```
struct A {
  A(int x) {}
};

struct B : virtual public A {
  using A::A;
};

struct C : virtual public A {
  using A::A;
};

struct D : virtual public B, public C {
  D(int x) : B(x), C(x) {}
};

int main() {
  D d(1);
}
```

The compiler is complaining that:

```
error: constructor for 'D' must explicitly initialize the base
      class 'A' which does not have a default constructor
  D(int x) : B(x), C(x) {}
```

But, I don't really have access to `A` from `D`... How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: But you do have access to `A`.

Comment: The compiler literally tells you what to do. `D(int x) : A(x), B(x), C(x) {}`

Comment: GCC has very poor diagnostics for this error. I'm guessing CLANG is the compiler you are using which is showing the solution in the error.

Comment: If you're planning on using this for production code, before you go much further ask yourself, "Do I want a complex Inheritance structure? I understand it, but will the co-op who's assigned to maintaining it understand it? Am I trapping myself into being the only person who can maintain this code for the next 40 years?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have an access to `A` since you're inheriting from it.

You would have to call the constructor of `A` in order to construct the object `D`.
Your `D` constructor should look something like that :
 `D(int x) : A(x), B(x), C(x) {}`
Because of the multiple inheritance, constructors of `B` and `C` would ignore the `A(x)` part and you will have only one object which is `D`.

Comment: This makes sense, but I wonder: suppose I create another class E that inherits D. The compiler asks me to also instantiate A from E, despite the fact that D's constructor already creates the A instance for B and C. To put it simply, my question is : why do all the classes inheriting D must also explicitely initialize A ?

Comment: @Michael: That's just how virtual inheritance works: it's viral, because any new derived class might derive from the common base _again_ and thus necessitate a new "final say" on how to initialize it.  It's very common to just insist on default-initializing virtual bases for this reason.  Note that there's not even a way to say "inherit from `B` and `C` with _one_ shared `A` subobject and from unrelated `X` and `Y` with _another_ shared `A` subobject"; the language feature simply has limitations.